# Turning Recorded Audio into numerical data

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, fft, waveform

I am making a Java personal project where you can record yourself singing a song, and the program will load a song (from a preselected small selection) that best matches that melody. So far, I have implemented the ability for the user to record an audio file as a WAVE file using the Java Sound API. I have seen that for audio similarity, one can perform correlation between the audio files, and by measuring if there is a high magnitude peak in the correlation graph one can determine if the audio files are similar.

I read the following post in the Signal Processing stack exchange
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar which talks about using the Fast Fourier transform to accomplish convolution (correlation that works for time-delayed audio). I have imported the JTransforms project on Github to use FFT, but I am unsure how to turn the WAVE files into a numerical representation (something like a large array of values) that I can use to perform correlation or convolution. Any advice on how to go about this is much appreciated!

Comment: Hello, this site does not work like this :D you have to show us some details/code to get help, that will show you that you were trying to solve the problem.

Comment: audio lives in the time domain where you have a curve which wobbles up and down yet goes flat to the zero crossing line typically a value of zero for silence  . wobbles range from max negative to max positive on a signed integer .. for starters to ignore FFT simply iterate across both audio sources simultaneously and sum into one total value as your multiply together each sample pair taken from each source recording ... if both input source files match this sum total will be large ... to align in time both recordings you may need to repeat above  for entire file while introducing a time offset

Comment: first link on google: `how to compare two .wav files`: https://audiophilestyle.com/forums/topic/20872-comparing-two-wav-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a .wav, you will be using the class `AudioInputStream`. An example is provided in the tutorial "[Using Files and Format Converters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html) It's the first code example in the article, in the sections "Reading Sound Files".

The next hurdle is translating the bytes into meaningful PCM. In the code example above, there is a comment line that reads:

```
  // Here, do something useful with the audio data that's 
  // now in the audioBytes array...
```

That is the point where you can convert the bytes to PCM. The exact algorithm depends on the format which you can inspect via `AudioInputStream`'s `getFormat` method, which returns an `AudioFormat`.

The format will tell you how many bytes per PCM value (e.g., 16-bit encoding is two bytes per PCM value) and the byte order, which can be little- or big-endian. If the audio is stereo, the PCM values alternate between left and right.

The building of the PCM values from the bytes involves bit shifting. I'm guessing you know how to handle this. The natural result of creating 16-bit values, assuming the data is signed PCM format, would be signed short integers. So, the last step is often division by the Short.MAX_VALUE to convert the shorts to signed floats ranging from -1 to 1.